# Is Google Play Store and having google account required for clients to use GCM?

Tags: android, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

I read about Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) and I liked it but I am afraid of drawbacks and misunderstanding

1)Do we have to force the client app end users to have at least one google account to enable the usage of GCM?

2)Is Google Play Store required for clients to use GCM?

if yes, Is it done by the client app user or by the server app side user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do we have to force the client app end users to have at least one google account to enable the usage of GCM?

On older devices, yes. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html):

> For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

> Is Google Play Store required for clients to use GCM?

No, but the Google Services Framework is required, and usually devices with the Google Services Framework have the Play Store.